# Visual Studio broken reference version

Tags: visual-studio

I have a visual studio project with some broken references.

`<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />`

I noticed this can be fixed by changing it to

`<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />`

However, since I have a lot broken references I'd like to make those dlls available on my system instead. How can i do that?

Comment: You'd have to [install .NET 3.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows), no longer available by default on a Win10 machine.  Getting a bit long in the tooth, targeting 3.0 or 3.5 doesn't make much sense anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant This actually solved my issue. I tought that checking ".NET Framework 3.5 development tools" from the VS installer application would have been enough. But it seems it's not

Answer (score 0):

Update the project to use .Net 4.8 which will have a supported `ServiceModel`. Since that module primarily deals with http traffic, the need to update it to a more secure version is reason enough to justify the upgrade.